# Request not working in NodeJS but working in Python

Tags: python, node.js, post, request

The following code is an extract from Postman, where I am getting a response. For some reason the NodeJS version doesn't seem to be running and gives a "Socket hang up" error, where as the python version runs well. Both codes are pasted below:

```
const obj = {
  asset: [
    {
      age: "33",
      existingDisease: false,
      gender: "MALE",
      id: "883a8cb5446f4d6780db2e59bdf4ee35",
      proposerRelationShip: "SELF",
      used: false,
    },
  ],
  cover: [],
  pinCode: "122001",
  quoteId: "7637d7ff982145569fbfa604e3b74485",
  sumInsured: "700000",
  term: { unit: "YEAR", value: "1" },
};

const strObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://sa.navi.com/v3/premium?paymentMode=SUBSCRIPTION",
  headers: {
    appversion: "2.2.4",
    appversioncode: "92",
    osversion: "Android_11",
    deviceid: "3e44626c3bb37d4c",
    defaultlocale: "en_US",
    "x-session-token": "d635eb15-10aa-4315-9122-6ed3627dc1b8",
    "x-click-stream-data":
      '{"app":{"name":"Navi","version":"92","version_name":"2.2.4"},"device":{"device_id":"3e44626c3bb37d4c","advertising_id":"706649fa-50f0-410d-9c17-3085201808e2","manufacturer":"Google","model":"sdk_gphone_x86","os":"Android","os_version":"30"},"network":{"carrier":"Android","type":"Wifi"},"location":{"latitude":"37.4219983","longitude":"-122.084"},"user":{}}',
    "x-target": "GI",
    source: "APK",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "419",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip",
    "user-agent": "okhttp/4.9.0",
  },
  body: strObj,
};

console.log("Going to trigger API");
console.log(options);
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Gives error:

Error: Error: socket hang up

While the same code in Python works:

```
url = "https://sa.navi.com/v3/premium?paymentMode=SUBSCRIPTION"

payload = "{\"asset\":[{\"age\":\"33\",\"existingDisease\":false,\"gender\":\"MALE\",\"id\":\"883a8cb5446f4d6780db2e59bdf4ee35\",\"proposerRelationShip\":\"SELF\",\"used\":false}],\"cover\":[],\"pinCode\":\"122001\",\"quoteId\":\"7637d7ff982145569fbfa604e3b74485\",\"sumInsured\":\"700000\",\"term\":{\"unit\":\"YEAR\",\"value\":\"1\"}}"
headers = {
  'appversion': '2.2.4',
  'appversioncode': '92',
  'osversion': 'Android_11',
  'deviceid': '3e44626c3bb37d4c',
  'defaultlocale': 'en_US',
  'x-session-token': 'd635eb15-10aa-4315-9122-6ed3627dc1b8',
  'x-click-stream-data': '{"app":{"name":"Navi","version":"92","version_name":"2.2.4"},"device":{"device_id":"3e44626c3bb37d4c","advertising_id":"706649fa-50f0-410d-9c17-3085201808e2","manufacturer":"Google","model":"sdk_gphone_x86","os":"Android","os_version":"30"},"network":{"carrier":"Android","type":"Wifi"},"location":{"latitude":"37.4219983","longitude":"-122.084"},"user":{}}',
  'x-target': 'GI',
  'source': 'APK',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  'content-length': '419',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/4.9.0'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `content-length` is wrong (you're passing 419, when the actual length of your payload JSON is 279).  This probably means the receiving server is still waiting for the rest of the content to arrive, it never arrives so eventually the server times out and hangs up on you (thus why you get a hang up error).

And, lo and behold, when I just remove the `content-length` header and let the request library compute it automatically, the request starts working for me.

As for the python implementation, one guess is that it is overriding the wrong content-length and fixing it for you.

---

FYI, the `request()` library has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) and it is not recommended that people write new code with it as it will not be advanced with new features in the future.  A list of suggested alternatives (that all support promises) is [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite in that list is `got()` which also supports most of the same options as the `request()` library, but is promise-based at is core and has a number of API improvements that make it easier to use (in my opinion).

And, indeed your code works just fine with the `got()` library (after removing the incorrect `content-length` header).

```
const got = require('got');

const obj = {
    asset: [{
        age: "33",
        existingDisease: false,
        gender: "MALE",
        id: "883a8cb5446f4d6780db2e59bdf4ee35",
        proposerRelationShip: "SELF",
        used: false,
    }, ],
    cover: [],
    pinCode: "122001",
    quoteId: "7637d7ff982145569fbfa604e3b74485",
    sumInsured: "700000",
    term: { unit: "YEAR", value: "1" },
};

const strObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://sa.navi.com/v3/premium?paymentMode=SUBSCRIPTION",
    headers: {
        appversion: "2.2.4",
        appversioncode: "92",
        osversion: "Android_11",
        deviceid: "3e44626c3bb37d4c",
        defaultlocale: "en_US",
        "x-session-token": "d635eb15-10aa-4315-9122-6ed3627dc1b8",
        "x-click-stream-data": '{"app":{"name":"Navi","version":"92","version_name":"2.2.4"},"device":{"device_id":"3e44626c3bb37d4c","advertising_id":"706649fa-50f0-410d-9c17-3085201808e2","manufacturer":"Google","model":"sdk_gphone_x86","os":"Android","os_version":"30"},"network":{"carrier":"Android","type":"Wifi"},"location":{"latitude":"37.4219983","longitude":"-122.084"},"user":{}}',
        "x-target": "GI",
        source: "APK",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip",
        "user-agent": "okhttp/4.9.0",
    },
    body: strObj,
};

console.log("Going to trigger API");
got(options).then(response => {
    console.log(response.body);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much good sir, this worked like a charm